# Sentinel 2p Averaging Kernel

Tags: methane

I am looking to get an averaging kernel (methane related calculations) for Sentinel 2 like the one for TROPOMI? Where do I find it? Trying to use this for simulating observed column concentrations from methane concentrations generated from dispersion models.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The Sentinel 2 level 1 and level 2 products are just (color) bands in the electromagnetic spectrum, not column/atmosphere-averaged properties. As such, they are free of averaging kernels.